# .NET web.sitemap not found

Tags: .net

I am trying to submit my web.sitemap to Google and it's indicating a 404 Error.
Does anyone know of a better way to access this sitemap in the URL?  Or am I missing something in the web.config?

I have tried to access this directly in the URL which returns:
XML Parsing Error: no element found

http://www.davincispainting.com/web.sitemap

I read that this is required in the web.config, however, I am not using a XMLSiteMapProvider:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
   <providers>
      <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
         description="Default SiteMap provider."
         type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider "
         siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
         securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
   </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Here is my web.sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
<siteMapNode url="painting" title="Home"  description="Davincis Painters in Northern Virginia">
  <siteMapNode url="painters" title="About Davinci's Painting"  description="About Davincis Painting" />
  <siteMapNode url="CoreValues" title="Our Painting Values"  description="Davinci's Painitng Values" />
  <siteMapNode url="OurProcess" title="Our Painting Process"  description="Davinci's Painting Process" />
  <siteMapNode url="Green" title="Environmental Friendly Processes"  description="Davinci's Environmental Friendly Processes" />
  <siteMapNode url="WhyDavincis" title="Why Select Davinci's"  description="Why Select Davinci's" />
  <siteMapNode url="ServiceAreas" title="Our Service Areas"  description="Davinci's Service Areas">
    <siteMapNode url="reston-painters" title="Painting in Reston"  description="Reston Painting" />
    <siteMapNode url="alexandria-painters" title="Painting in Alexandria"  description="Alexandria Painting" />
    <siteMapNode url="vienna-painters" title="Painting in Vienna"  description="Vienna Painting" />
    <siteMapNode url="arlington-painters" title="Painting in Arlington"  description="Arlington Painting" />
    <siteMapNode url="fairfax-painters" title="Painting in Fairfax"  description="Fairfax Painting" />
    <siteMapNode url="mclean-painters" title="Painting in Mclean"  description="Mclean Painting" />
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url="InteriorServices" title="Interior Painting Services"  description="Davinci's Interior Painting Services" />
  <siteMapNode url="ExteriorServices" title="Exterior Painting Services"  description="Davinci's Exterior Painting Services" />
  <siteMapNode url="Faux" title="Faux Finishing Services"  description="Davinci's Faux Finishing Services" />
  <siteMapNode url="InteriorGallery" title="Interior Painting Pictures"  description="Davinci's Interior Painting Pictures" />
  <siteMapNode url="ExteriorGallery" title="Exterior Painting Pictures"  description="Davinci's Exterior Painting Pictures" />
  <siteMapNode url="Drywall" title="Drywall Photographs"  description="Davinci's Drywall Photographs" />
  <siteMapNode url="Testimonials" title="Client Testimonials"  description="Davinci's Client Testimonials" />
  <siteMapNode url="blog" title="Davinci's Painting Information"  description="Davinci's Painting Information" />
  <siteMapNode url="StartUpGuide" title="Painting Customer Guide"  description="Davinci's Painting Customer Guide" />
  <siteMapNode url="ColorSelector" title="Color Selector"  description="Davinci's Color Selector" />
  <siteMapNode url="PaintingFacts" title="Painting Facts"  description="Davinci's Painting Facts" />
  <siteMapNode url="Glossary" title="Painting Glossary"  description="Davinci's Painting Glossary" />
  <siteMapNode url="Safety" title="Painting Safety"  description="Davinci's Painting Safety" />
  <siteMapNode url="painting-solutions" title="Painting Solutions" description="Davinci's Painting Solutions">
    <siteMapNode url="painting-answers" title="Painting Answers" description="Painting Solutions and Answers" />
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url="GeneralContact" title="General Contact Form"  description="General Contact Form" />
  <siteMapNode url="Estimate" title="Schedule an Estimate"  description="Estimate Schedule Form" />
  <siteMapNode url="DayEstimate" title="Schedule a Day Estimate"  description="Day Estimate Schedule Form" />
</siteMapNode>
```

Comment: what's the method you use to submit your sitemap to Google?

Comment: @voddy I'm using Webmaster Tools

Comment: try using following tool. Said to be easier. I haven't used though.  http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-xml-sitemap/

Comment: @voddy this is a plugin for Wordpress.  Mine is a simple .NET website.

Comment: OK. What's the URL you use to access your sitemap? Is it similar to     http://sites.google.com/site/YourSite/system/feeds/sitemap   ?

Comment: @voddy I think that's what Im trying to figure out.  I only know that I have web.Sitemap

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49202/discussion-between-voddy-and-paul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you then.

[submitting sitemap](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en)

I cant see anything wrong with your sitemap or the web.config. Good luck anyways

Comment: per those instructions indicate to add: /system/feeds/sitemap into the Add Sitemap Textbox,,,, however this still results in 404 Error,,,, How are you able to see this sitemap?